# Updating a parent's state which is mapped through the child is not re-rendering parent component

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a function inside of the parent which is passed as a prop to the child and then called. When this function is called, the state of the parent is updated. The state is a list that is mapped in the parent but the .map does not re-render in the parent in react. When the component is actually re-rendered it updates on screen but not when initially changed through setState();

Here is a link to a simplified replication of the code I created on code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-faraday-hwyve?file=/src/App.js
(The state is updated when clicking the text "Hello codeSandBox by the way)

I added comments to show the flow from parent to the child a bit if that helps and you can also see that the state is indeed updated in the console but not updated on-screen until the file is saved again or another state changes that forces a refresh of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the list solved my problem. I used the index of the filer and compared it to the index passed into the function (or in the case of the codesandbox just the set index 2).

```
    const deleteEvent = (identity) => {
        setList(eventList.filter((item, index) => index !== identity));
}
```